# Java in-memory map with string key part reuse

Tags: java, dictionary, trie, prefix-tree

I have tens of thousands of records in a map. Map keys are string like `s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/03/file.txt`, `s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/04/file.txt`, value is `0` or `1`.
So far I use HashMap but the memory usage is too high, I want to reduce it.

I am looking for a something that is key-value and utilizes key part reusability.
What comes to mind naturally is the use some tree structure to store the prefixes.

Could somebody point to an appropriate implementation, preferably lightweight?

Comment: Are many values 0? If so, can you treat "key doesn't exist" just like "key exists but with a value of 0"? If so, you can use a HashSet of HashSet of ... Otherwise, you can use a HashMap of HashMap of ...

Comment: @JeffHolt Hash implementations are still very memory intensive because prefixes are not re-used.

Comment: If you have a "hash of a hash of a hash of a hash....", then there are *no* duplication of prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Prefix Tree` is a possible solution that will be lightweight in terms of space complexity. Here is a `Java` implementation of a `Prefix Tree` using `Trie`. I used a `HashMap` for the `child` as I'm not sure of the alphabet size. You can definitely use a fixed length for the `child` `TrieNode` if you are certain about the alphabet size in your dictionary. Each `TrieNode` will store the `value` of the key only if the `TrieNode` marks the end of the string. When you find the `TrieNode` which stores the last `character` of your key, you can then access the `value`;

```
class TrieNode {
    HashMap<Character, TrieNode> child;
    boolean isEnd;
    int value;

    TrieNode() {
        this.child = new HashMap<>();
    }

}

public class PrefixTree {
    private TrieNode root;

    public PrefixTree() {
        this.root = new TrieNode();
    }

    public void put(String key, int value) {
        char[] data = key.toCharArray();
        TrieNode tempNode = root;

        for (char ch : data) {
            if (tempNode.child.get(ch) == null) {
                tempNode.child.put(ch, new TrieNode());
            }
            tempNode = tempNode.child.get(ch);

        }
        tempNode.isEnd = true;
        tempNode.value = value;
    }


    public TrieNode get(String key) {
        char[] data = key.toCharArray();
        TrieNode tempNode = root;
        for (char ch : data) {
            if (tempNode.child.get(ch) == null) {
                return null;
            }
            tempNode = tempNode.child.get(ch);
        }
        if (tempNode != null && tempNode.isEnd == false)
            return null;

        return tempNode;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {
                "s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/03/file.txt",
                "s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/04/file.txt",
                "s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/05/file.txt",
                "s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/06/file.txt",
                "s3://mybucket/some/path/2021/03/07/file.txt",
        };
        PrefixTree prefixTree = new PrefixTree();
        Random random = new Random();

        for(String key: input){
            prefixTree.put(key, random.nextInt(2)); // inserts 0-1 randomly
        }

        System.out.println(prefixTree.get(input[1]).value);

        // Update functionality demo
        prefixTree.put(input[1], prefixTree.get(input[1]).value+3);

        // value will be updated
        System.out.println(prefixTree.get(input[1]).value);

    }
}
```